# mongodb using projection in $filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have inserted a sample document

```
db.test.insert({
    x:1, 
    a:[
        {b:1,c:1,d:1},
        {b:2,c:2}
      ]
})
```

I am facing 2 problems when I try to use $fitler aggregation as in my below query

```
db.test.aggregate(
{$project:{ 
  a:{$filter:{
    input : '$a',
    as : 'item',
    cond : '$$item.d'
  }}
}}
)
```

## Element Existence

1] How do I test the existence of **element a.d**, I found a way of just using **cond : '$$item.d'**, but I think there should be a better way of doing it.

## Selective Projection

2] How do I selectively project **b and d nodes**.
I tried the below code and it works, but I think there is a pipeline in projection as well. Therefore I applied projection twice on the same node 1 for filtering array elements, 2 for array element nodes

```
db.test.aggregate(
{$project:{ 
  a:{$filter:{
    input : '$a',
    as : 'item',
    cond : '$$item.d'
  }},
  a:{b:1, d:1}
}}
)
```

I seem to get the solution, but I think there may be a better way. Thanks for reply!

Comment: for Element Existence, why don't you use a $match after [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array? Doing that, you'll have only object with a `d` (sorry about that ^^)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(1) It appears to me that the $exists operator is not yet unavailable in aggregation pipelines.  You may wish to check if there is a jira requesting this, and if so, watch it and vote for it, and if not, add one?

Your workaround, I believe, will only return cases where item.d is true, rather than when it exists.  So if item.d == null, false, 0, it will not be returned.  I would suggest trying this instead:

```
cond : { $gte : [ '$$item.d', null ] }
```

(2) I'm not 100% sure I understood the question, but if I do, I think the way to do it is to have two $project's in the pipeline.  So something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate( 
 [ { $project:
     {a:{$filter:{input:'$a',as:'item',cond:{$gte:['$$item.d',null]}}}}
   },
   { $project: { a : { b : 1, d : 1 } } }
 ]
)
```

Comment: We're now in 2023 and this answer helped me greatly. 
I tried to use $exists, but it seems still not being available, or I don't know the syntax well enough. Someone knows ?
I'm using mongo 4.2 and I was hoping to find it here
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/

Even in the doc for 6.0 I couldn't find it
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Thanks for all help !!